# Trying to build Mozilla got this error when trying to open start-shell-msvc2015

Tags: batch-file, mozilla

I am trying to build Mozilla on Windows 7 64bit

I tried to run this start-shell-msvc2015.bat but got this error.

MozillaBuild Install Directory: C:\mozilla-build\
Visual C++ 2015 Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\V
C\
Windows SDK Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\

Unable to call a suitable vcvars script. Exiting.

Press any key to continue . . .

I did everything according to their instructions

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, [search Google for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=mozilla+build+"Unable+to+call+a+suitable+vcvars+script."). From [the first result](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1212753):

> *Hallvord R. M. Steen*: 
>   To anybody else who might have this problem: it's caused by choices made during installation, and the installer options were somewhat confusing. I don't remember the exact details, but I think the "Default" installation no longer gives you the required scripts - the "Default vs custom" section on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw%28v=vs.140%29.aspx seems to confirm that you need to choose "Custom" during install and enable Visual C++ tools specifically.
>
> *Andrew Overholt*: You're right, Hallvord. I went back to my VS2015 installation .exe download, clicked "Modify [the existing installation]" and picked "Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015" under "Programming Languages" > "Visual C++".

Also you'll need at least update 3 if you're using the VS2015 Community Edition. From that Mozilla dev docs page:

> Once you’re up to date, download and install [Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) from Microsoft. If you have an earlier version of Visual Studio, you'll need to upgrade; Firefox relies on C++ features that aren't supported in older versions of Visual Studio. Do not accept the default configuration. Instead, select **Programming Languages > Visual C++ > Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015.*

See also [this question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/944951/no-windows-sdk-found-when-installing-spidermonkey).

Furthermore, the MDN docs [actually were updated with this info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites$compare?locale=en-US&to=972959&from=948759) after that report, and indeed [the current build instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites) contain, in bold:

> Be sure to **install the "Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015", which requires a customized installation in Visual Studio 2015.**

In the prerequisites section.

Also you'll need at least update 3 if you're using the VS2015 Community Edition. From that Mozilla dev docs page:

> Once you’re up to date, download and install [Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) from Microsoft. If you have an earlier version of Visual Studio, you'll need to upgrade; Firefox relies on C++ features that aren't supported in older versions of Visual Studio. Do not accept the default configuration. Instead, select **Programming Languages > Visual C++ > Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015.**

Comment: I don't see where is customized options are. I am using the community version. Click everhting that is C++ in it

Comment: @WenBoMa From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites: *"Once you’re up to date, download and install Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3 from Microsoft. If you have an earlier version of Visual Studio, you'll need to upgrade; Firefox relies on C++ features that aren't supported in older versions of Visual Studio. Do not accept the default configuration. Instead, select Programming Languages > Visual C++ > Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015."*. Do you have update 3?

Comment: I do have Update 3 and Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 installed. Interesting observation the start-shell-msvc2013 works but the start-shell-msvc2015 doesn't work

Comment: well it fail in mach build with this error
mozmake.EXE[1]: Leaving directory 'c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central'
client.mk:170: recipe for target 'build' failed
mozmake.EXE: *** [build] Error 2